# Why is Integral from $a$ to $b$ equal to negative integral from $b$ to $a$

Tags: calculus, integration, definition

Why is the integral from $a$ to $b$ equal to negative integral from $b$ to $a$. According to my teacher this is a definition, but definitions still have some logic/reasoning behind it, so what is the logic/reasoning in this case?

Comment: For $a<b<c$, we have 

$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx+\int_b^c f(x)\,dx=\int_a^cf(x)\,dx\tag 1$$

If $(1)$ holds regardless of the order of $a$, $b$, and $c$, then for $a=c$ we arrive at 

$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx+\int_b^a f(x)\,dx=\int_a^af(x)\,dx=0$$

Comment: Or directly use definition of the Riemann integral? (Riemann sums that is)

Comment: I wouldn’t say it is definition, moreover just corollary from the definition of an integral by Riemann sums (at the calc 1 level). I like to call things “facts” when they are things we use but not prove in class, rather than saying it’s definition.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  OP is not asking for a definition or a proof, but rather intuition for why this is the way it is.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt How does it follow from the definition of a Riemann sum? The Riemann sum is defined for $[a,b]$ with $a<b$.

Answer (score 10):

It's so that the equality$$\int_a^cf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_b^cf(x)\,\mathrm dx$$always holds.

Comment: OP, try the case where a=c (you expect the LHS to be zero, right?)

Comment: But *why* should that equality even work? It is proved for $a<c<b$ not $a≤c≤b$, no?

Comment: @William If $c=a$ or $c=b$, the equality is trivial.

Answer (score 4):

From the Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus it follows that $$ \int_{a}^{b}f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = F(b) - F(a) $$
where $F$ is a function such that $F'= f$ and $b > a$.

If we want to extend this result to all choices of $a$ and $b$ that define a 
closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$ we should be consistent with the theorem so
$$ \int_{b}^{a}f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = F(a) - F(b) = -\int_{a}^{b}f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x $$
Another motivation for this is that it allows for expressions like
$$F(x)= \int_{x_0}^{x}f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t $$ to be functions defined in any real 
interval (as long as the integral makes sense of course).

Answer (score 3):

When I first learned this, I thought of it like this.  Let's say $a < b$, and you're integrating the function $f'$, which is the derivative of some function $f$.  If you're integrating from $a$ to $b$, what you're doing is taking a sum $\int$ of a bunch of small changes in $y$:

$$\int\limits_a^b f'(x)dx = \int\limits_a^b \frac{dy}{dx}dx = \int\limits_a^b dy$$

That is, you're adding an infinite number of small changes in $y = f(x)$, like $dy = f(x_2)- f(x_1)$, for $x_1 < x_2$ infinitely close together, a little bit at a time, starting at $a$, until you get to $b$.  Then

$$\int\limits_b^a dy$$

is just the reverse process. This time you start at $b$ and work your way down to $a$.  So you'd be adding up infinitely many infinitely  small changes like $dy = f(x_2) - f(x_1)$ for $x_2 < x_1$.  Clearly each small change here is the negative of one you encountered before. So

$$\int\limits_a^b f'(x)dx = \int\limits_a^b dy =- \int\limits_b^a dy = -\int\limits_b^a \frac{dy}{dx}dx=-\int\limits_b^a f'(x)dx$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = F(x)\Big|_a^b=F(b)-F(a)=-\Big[F(a)-F(b)\Big]=-\Big[F(x)\Big]_b^a=-\int_b^a f(x)\,dx$$